# Вопрос по «merge», языка sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть таблица устройств (*DEVICE*) в БД на *FireBird* (с полями «*Наименование*», «*Тип*», «*Зав.номер*» и т.д.) в которую из *Excel* экспортируются данные (устройства).
В БД добавилась вторая таблица «*Человеко/часы*» (*NORM_HOURS*), в которой нужно **содержать только** поля «*Наименование*» и «*Тип*» этих устройств ну и еще некоторые поля отличные от полей в *DEVICE*.
Т.е. в *NORM_HOURS* должны содержаться только уникальные устройства по оговоренным двум полям.

После экспорта устройств из файла в *DEVICE*, я делаю операцию «*MERGE*», для таблицы *NORM_HOURS*, чтоб эти устройства появились в *NORM_HOURS*.

```
merge into NORM_HOURS nh using DEVICES d on ((nh.NAME_DEVICE=d.NAME_DEVICE and nh.TYPE_DEVICE=d.TYPE_DEVICE))
   when matched then
   update set nh.NAME_DEVICE=d.NAME_DEVICE, nh.TYPE_DEVICE=d.TYPE_DEVICE
   when not matched then
   insert (nh.ID, nh.NAME_DEVICE, nh.TYPE_DEVICE, nh.USER_ID, nh.DEPARTMENT_ID, nh.TYPE_INPUT)
    values (GEN_ID(GEN_ID_NORM_HOURS, 1), d.NAME_DEVICE, d.TYPE_DEVICE, 1, 2, 3)
```

Вопросы по данной теме:
**1**. можно ли провести операцию «*MERGE*» делать не для всей таблицы *DEVICE*, а только для некоторых ее строк, скажем в которых *d.PROPOSAL_ID=7* например?
**2**. если вдруг у меня *d.TYPE_DEVICE* пусто, а *d.NAME_DEVICE* заполнено, то такие строки продолжают вставляться, при повторном проведении скрипта (не смотря на то, что они в *NORM_HOURS* уже есть), можно ли как-нибудь избавиться от повторной вставки?
**3**. и правильно ли будет если я из скрипта уберу строки:

> when matched then    update set nh.NAME_DEVICE=d.NAME_DEVICE,
>   nh.TYPE_DEVICE=d.TYPE_DEVICE

? Просто я НЕ хочу обновлять те строки в NORM_HOURS, которые уже в ней есть

Answer (score 0):

1. Да. Перечитайте Firebird Language Reference. Это может быть не только таблица, но и подзапрос.
2. Если под "пусто" вы понимаете значение NULL, то используйте вместо "=" предикат "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM". Он дает положительный результат при сравнени равных и при сравнении двух NULL'ов.
3. Да. Не просто правильно, на настоятельно рекомендуется. Вы обновляете только те строки, которые уже заведомо содержат правильную информацию.

И от себя. У вас денормализованная база. Вместо пары NAME_DEVICE, TYPE_DEVICE в NORM_HOURS должно быть одно поле - DEVICE_ID

Comment: Про DEVICE_ID - скажу - все верно, если бы таблица "NORM_HOURS" не была классификатор (откуда нельзя удалять записи). Потому что из других таблиц это делать можно

Answer (score 0):

Да немного переделал запрос, например:

```
merge into NORM_HOURS nh using (SELECT * FROM DEVICES WHERE PROPOSAL_ID=10) d
on (nh.NAME_DEVICE=d.NAME_DEVICE and nh.TYPE_DEVICE=d.TYPE_DEVICE)
   when not matched then
   insert (nh.ID, nh.NAME_DEVICE, nh.TYPE_DEVICE, nh.USER_ID, nh.DEPARTMENT_ID, nh.TYPE_INPUT)
    values (GEN_ID(GEN_ID_NORM_HOURS, 1), d.NAME_DEVICE, d.TYPE_DEVICE, 1, 2, 3)
```